# Not able to fetch the complete source code from the PHP script

Tags: php, web-scraping

```
<?php 
$url = "http://www.justdial.com/Delhi-NCR/Pizza-Outlets-%3Cnear%3E-Okhla/";
$ptr = fopen("op.txt","w");
$data = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($data);
$result = htmlentities($data);
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
@$doc->loadHTML($result);
$finder = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node = $finder->query("//h3[contains(@class, 'r')]");
?>
```

Above is the code which I have written to fetch the source code of justdial. The only output which I get is the first pizza outlet.How can I fetch all the results which are shown on the justdial website.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's invalid php. You need `print_r($data);` instead of `print_r $data;`

Comment: What is $data showing. After `print_r($data);`?

Comment: only "Nathus Sweets" is present in $data. 
No "Slice of Italy" etc are present. Why is it so?

Comment: You need to print_r($result). I'm getting al the information. If it is not the case. Check your php version and are you using it locally ?

Comment: are you getting "Slice of Italy" in $data? My php version is 5.5.9 and yes I am using it on local_host

Comment: Ah now i get it. You are getting a cross domain error. This is why the the website is getting blocked

Answer (score 0):

All items are part of the '<div id="tab_block">' html element which its content is built by javascript/AJAX calls, so they cannot appear in the HTML file you load via file_get_contents() since you will get the HTML definition only without the javascript code being interpreted.

However, it means you can access the items/database directly by code if you know the endpoints.

For example (url are shown as when I tested them)

This [url](http://www.justdial.com/functions/sortbyphotosnew.php?contractid=011PXX11.XX11.151106170721.W5H9$$6$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.140302105210.Y9N8$$5$$Delhi$$1$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.140131144524.H2P9$$5$$delhi$$1$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.141207181743.C1H7$$5$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.141030090123.Y4L4$$5$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.150324124753.C1Z4$$5$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.150324123243.Y4L5$$5$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.150415120028.X4Z5$$5$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.150728180404.A7Y5$$5$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0,011PXX11.XX11.150103172503.K9E6$$5$$Delhi$$0$$1$$0&cases=citycheck&pagename=result) will return the first few items of the complete list. It will return something like (in JSON format):

```
[{docid: "011PXX11.XX11.151106170721.W5H9",…}, {docid: "011PXX11.XX11.140302105210.Y9N8",…},…]
  0: {docid: "011PXX11.XX11.151106170721.W5H9",…}
      disp_pic: "http://images.jdmagicbox.com/delhi/h9/011pxx11.xx11.151106170721.w5h9/catalogue/6cf575ffbd1090f5a314d2cf40451c88.jpg"
      docid: "011PXX11.XX11.151106170721.W5H9"
  1: {docid: "011PXX11.XX11.140302105210.Y9N8",…}
      disp_pic: "http://images.jdmagicbox.com/delhi/n8/011pxx11.xx11.140302105210.y9n8/catalogue/ecfd2106644df17013e98bb60f40c527.jpg"
      docid: "011PXX11.XX11.140302105210.Y9N8"
      video: "http://videos.jdmagicbox.com/delhi/n8/011pxx11.xx11.140302105210.y9n8/video/fc2a62242ae03c74c15436dbcc04c33a_m.jpg"
  ...
```

the docid can be used to do further query on a particular item, while the [disp_pic](http://images.jdmagicbox.com/delhi/h9/011pxx11.xx11.151106170721.w5h9/catalogue/6cf575ffbd1090f5a314d2cf40451c88.jpg) url will return the image

This [url](http://content4.jdmagicbox.com/delhi/h9/011pxx11.xx11.151106170721.w5h9/catalogue/6cf575ffbd1090f5a314d2cf40451c88.jpg?output-quality=60) will return the image of the 1st item too but use some parameters

In any case, I just scratch the surface of the whole issue to demonstrate how to proceed. You would need to understand the site logic to read the complete dataset, but it would be easier to contact the webmaster and ask him to describe its API/endpoints for you to access the data. As well as asking him permission to use it even if the 'API' is not protected.

Once you know the endpoint, structure and data description, you can use a PHP library like mashape\unirest to do queries like this:

```
Unirest\Request::verifyPeer (false) ;
$response =Unirest\Request::get (
    'http://www.justdial.com/functions/sortbyphotosnew.php?contractid=011PXX11.XX11.151106170721.W...,
    array ( 'Accept' => 'application/json' ),
    null
) ;
```

if $response->code == 200 then the $response->body is your JSON object containing the document array.